# The process has been returned to the state before expression evaluation. (lldb)

Tags: ios, swift

Getting error while i sign in

```
DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
    let message = parseJSON["message"] as! String
    appDelegate.infoView(message: message, color: colorSmoothRed)
})
```

on line `let message = parseJson["message"] as! String`

> Error: Fatal Error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Answer (score 3):

The value of key "message" is nil sometimes, so you need to check it:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
     if let message = parseJSON["message"] as? String {
         appDelegate.infoView(message: message, color: colorSmoothRed)
     } else {
         //do something for no-message case
     }                     
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Read about [type casting](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TypeCasting.html).

Verify that type of the `parseJSON["message"]` is String before.

```
if let message = parseJSON["message"] as? String {

}
```